# How to use ValueNotifier inside ValueListenableBuilder in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using CustomScrollView and I need to search data inside 3 SliverList and 2 SliverGrid. All of them listen their data with ValueListenableBuilder and also I have an info box which shows if any data found or not. There are 5 `ValueNotifier<bool>` variables that helps me show/hide the info box but the problem is when the builders called again I need to call `ValueNotifier.value` inside this builders but it gives an error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

I know why this error happen, but I can't find any other solution, because I need to keep track of the status of the lists and grids **(Some of their items can be deleted and meanwhile I need to check again if new list or grid has a data)**

One of the SliverList:

```
Widget _taskWidgets() {
return SliverPadding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 22, 16, 16),
  sliver: ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: _taskService.listenable,
    builder: (_, __, child) {
      var tasks = _taskService.search(_keyword.value);
      _tasksEmpty.value = tasks.isEmpty; // this line gives error

      if (!_showCompleted.value) {
        tasks = tasks.where((e) => !e.completed).toList();
      }

      final listIDS = tasks.map((e) => e.listID).toSet();

      return SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((_, index) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
          final widget = HierarchyCard(tasks, index ~/ 2, true);

          if (index == 0) {
            return Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                widget,
                _text(_appLocalizations.searchTasks),
              ],
            );
          }

          return widget;
        }

        return const SizedBox(height: 30);
        }, childCount: 2 * listIDS.length - 1),
      );
    }
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are rebuilding a widget which is already being build

Try

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){

  _tasksEmpty.value = tasks.isEmpty;

});
```